# Swift-log package fails to compile on ubuntu

Tags: swift, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-1006-raspi aarch64) and Swift version 5.9.1 (swift-5.9.1-RELEASE)

I've previously had no issues compiling and running my programs using Logging but it's started failing with the error:

```
/(my package)/.build/checkouts/swift-log/Sources/Logging/Logging.swift:1392:64: error: value of optional type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<tm>?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<tm>'
        strftime(&buffer, buffer.count, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", localTime)
```

There's no error on macOS so is this an incompatibility in the `strftime` signature?

Any thoughts / ideas welcome!

Update: It compiles successfully on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS so this looks like a potential breaking change on Ubuntu....